# The suggested approach to deactivate an administrator account

Tags: system-admin, deactivate

We had an administrator who worked in our company for a certain period and there are a lot of things associated with his account. E.g. workflow rules, record owners, external services which use his account to login.

He has left the company for more than half a year now and we are planning to remove his account to reduce cost. So my question is what areas should I be looking at in order to safely deactivate his account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Considerations for Deactivating Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_deactivate_considerations.htm&type=0) and [Why can't I deactivate a system administrator?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-can-t-I-deactivate-a-system-administrator-1327108292639&language=en_US&type=1). I will not replicate these lists in full, because the links are a lot more descriptive, but here's an abbreviated list of things you need to check/be aware of.

Things that can prevent disabling administrators:

- Users in custom hierarchy fields
- Workflow email alert recipients
- Customer Portal Administrator users
- Default Web Creator
- Lead Process
- Assignment Rules
- Auto Response Rules
- Update Reminders
- Big Deal Alert
- Auto Response Rules
- Assignment Rules
- Support Settings
- Default Case Creator
- Automated Case Owner
- Task Assigned to the User
- Email Sent to the User
- Default Workflow User
- In an Approval Process/Approver/Delegated Approver

Other concerns:

- Accounts and opportunities owned by deactivated users
- Territories and forecasting
- Opportunity and account teams
- Account teams
- Opportunity teams
- Delegated external user administrators
- Salesforce Files
- Created By fields
- Record access

Comment: Thanks for that. If I understand correctly, this list doesn't cover external services using his credential?

Comment: Not that it matters now but this is an excellent reason why a dedicated api user account should be created for integrations and not use a user account