# Integration and Current Apex Jobs - User record

Tags: apex, integration

Our org has user created in Salesforce having Salesforce license assigned to it. It was set up for Integration and running apex jobs. Now I want to  know how we can disable the user and validate that user record is not being used for integration and/or current apex jobs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The documentation is pretty robust as far as deactivating of freezing users.

Comment: making this user inactive is not a problem but need to validate that making this user as inactive wont break any apex jobs or running integration in our salesforce environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no one trick to ensure nothing breaks, other than going through the org diligently. If you don't have good documentation on who runs what, this might be a good time to start.

If you have a full sandbox (or dev box) with integrations set up, that'd would be a good test to start to deactivate the user and see what happens. If need be, you can simply re-activate them and note what happened.

Otherwise, this answer linked below should contain all the various things you should check

[The suggested approach to deactivate an administrator account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194894/the-suggested-approach-to-deactivate-an-administrator-account)

I'd highlight querying all dashboards with the user as the running user and any scheduled apex being run as the user as typical ones.

```
SELECT Id,RunningUserId FROM Dashboard WHERE Type = 'LoggedInUser' AND RunningUserId = 'insert user id here'
```

Integrations from outside Salesforce are tricky, as you'll likely have no way of knowing if it's not documented. This is where having a sandbox with the integrations also set up will come in handy. If you do not have this, then you'll have to look at that users' login history and records last modified by the user to see if you can figure out what they're actually touching and connect the dots.